# How to call XmlReader.ReadToFollowing in case insensitive mode?

Tags: c#, xml

How to call  XmlReader.ReadToFollowing  in case  insensitive mode?

xml source can not be changed.

"settings" in XML can be: "SETTINGS","Settings" etc

```
using(StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader))
    {
        while (reader.ReadToFollowing("settings"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you going to be reading a very large amount of data? If the answer is no then I think that LINQ to XML ([XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) would be much easier for you to use rather than XMLReader.

//Karl-Henrik